# NSTableView doesn't show content data

Tags: objective-c, nstableview

I'm trying to show some content in my NSTableView in my mac app.

```
@implementation OpenTasksViewController {
    NSMutableArray *tasks;
}

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        tasks = [NSMutableArray array];
        [tasks addObject: [[Task alloc] initWithTitle:@"HI"]];
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView {
    return [tasks count];
}

- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    NSTableCellView *cell = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:tableColumn.identifier owner:self];
    Task *t = [tasks objectAtIndex:row];
    cell.textField.stringValue = t.title;

    return cell;
}
```

This class implements the NSTableViewDataSource and NSTableViewDelegate protocols.
Sadly, my app doesn't show the content.
I tried using reloadData, but that didn't work either.
When I debug into the project, the stringValue of cell.textField is correct.

Comment: check that your data source isn't null. may be you must retain it?

Comment: it is definitely not null. I tried both using it as a variable not being accessible from outside (no property) and as a '@property (strong, nonatomic)'. Still doens't work.